# Invariant Violation in api-platform demo / react-native generator

Tags: react-native, api-platform.com

I got an issue in the api-platform demo / generator react-native issue.
When i just follow steps here : https://api-platform.com/docs/client-generator/react-native/

I got this issue below.

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D686O.jpg)

I can paste my code if you need put i didnt add anything in all files.

Comment: Show me the screen code where you have a problem.